# %matplotlib line magic causes SyntaxError in Python script

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, spyder

I try to run the following codes on Spyder (Python 2.7.11):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

import tensorflow as tf

# settings
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4
# set to 20000 on local environment to get 0.99 accuracy
TRAINING_ITERATIONS = 2000        

DROPOUT = 0.5
BATCH_SIZE = 50

# set to 0 to train on all available data
VALIDATION_SIZE = 2000

# image number to output
IMAGE_TO_DISPLAY = 10
```

But I got this error:

```
line 10
    %matplotlib inline
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

I appreciate if anybody gives me an explanation.

P.S. the code is from Kaggle competition project: Digit Recognizer

Comment: Have you had any other scientific distributions installed? https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/264

Comment: I am using Anaconda for Python 2.7.11,  installed pandas, nump, scipy, matplotlib, scikit-learn 0.17. ....

Comment: also theano 0.8.0.dev0

Answer (score 79):

Line magics are only supported by the IPython command line. They cannot simply be used inside a script, because `%something` is not correct Python syntax.

If you want to do this from a script you have to get access to the IPython API and then call the `run_line_magic` function.

Instead of `%matplotlib inline`, you will have to do something like this in your script:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

A similar approach is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15898875/3005167), but it uses the deprecated `magic` function.

**Note that the script still needs to run in IPython.** Under vanilla Python the `get_ipython` function returns `None` and `get_ipython().run_line_magic` will raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Thank you  for  your suggestion. I tried your approach, and got another err: ImportError: No module named moves (because iPython is running the code "from six.moves import zip, reduce") , I am trying to find out why this happens.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion , but I got this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'run_line_magic'` , Can you help 
Thanks

Comment: @Always_Beginner this sounds like you are using a normal Python shell, in which case `get_ipython()` returns `None`. Line magics are only supported in IPython.

Comment: @kazemakase Okay but I thought this works for pure python too , as per this answer kazemakase [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724610/what-is-the-pure-python-equivalent-to-the-ipython-magic-function-call-matplotli) I thought it works for pure python too.

Comment: @Always_Beginner in the linked answer 'pure python' refers to the fact that line magics starting with `%` are not correct Python syntax, but using the functions `run_line_magic` or `magic` are syntactically correct "pure" Python. However, the line magic feature is only supported by the IPython interpreter and not by the normal Python interpreter.

Comment: This answer together with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39662359/10652754) check to see if the script is running on a interactive terminal works like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

Because line magics are only supported by the IPython command line not by Python cl, use: `'exec(%matplotlib inline)'` instead of `%matplotlib inline`

Answer (score 5):

The syntax '%' in `%matplotlib inline` is recognized by iPython (where it is set up to handle the magic methods), but not Python itself, which gives a SyntaxError. 
[Here is given one solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724610/what-is-the-pure-python-equivalent-to-the-ipython-magic-function-call-matplotli)

Comment: I thought this was the problem until I realized spyder is related to ipython, Then again this might be the problem.

Comment: Oops. Surprisingly, there are a lot of problems with matplotlib in Spyder.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However even I run the script on iPython console, it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @John, Make sure the script filename ends with .ipy as in:  ipython file.ipy .  If you use a .py file ending, ipython runs it as a regular python script and it doesn't work.  Also, "auto" can be used instead of "inline" for %matplotlib.

Answer (score 4):

If you include the following code at the top of your script, `matplotlib` will run inline when in an `IPython` environment (like jupyter, hydrogen atom plugin...), and it will still work if you launch the script directly via command line (`matplotlib` won't run inline, and the charts will open in a pop-ups as usual).

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ipy = get_ipython()
if ipy is not None:
    ipy.run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
```

Comment: Okay, if `ipy` is None then this solution doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons as to why this wouldn't work.

It is possible that matplotlib is not properly installed.
have you tried running:

```
conda install matplotlib
```

If that doesn't work, look at your %PATH% environment variable, does it contain your libraries and python paths?

[Similar problem on github anaconda](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/264)

Answer (score 0):

> This is the case you are using Julia:

The analogue of IPython's %matplotlib in Julia is to use the PyPlot package, which gives a Julia interface to Matplotlib including inline plots in IJulia notebooks. (The equivalent of numpy is already loaded by default in Julia.)
Given PyPlot, the analogue of %matplotlib inline is using PyPlot, since PyPlot defaults to inline plots in IJulia.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of %matplotlib inline,it is not a python script so we can write like this it will work
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

Comment: Spyder has an option for that. Please take a look at `Preferences > IPython console > Graphics` for it.