# How can I write code to be executed in interactive mode?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, pgf

My problem is similar to the one that is treated  [here]:([How can I check if code is executed in the IPython notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411967/how-can-i-check-if-code-is-executed-in-the-ipython-notebook)), but with an additional layer.

I am using some .py scripts with the special comment "# %%" that in visual studio code allow me to run some portions of the code interactively.
The problem is that i want to execute the following line only if i run the section in interactive mode, not if i run the entire script:

```
%matplotlib widget
```

I wish something like that would work:

```
if src.visualization.isNotebook():
    %matplotlib widget
```

where the function is defined as in the link:

```
def isNotebook() -> bool:
    try:
        shell = get_ipython().__class__.__name__
        if shell == 'ZMQInteractiveShell':
            return True   # Jupyter notebook or qtconsole
        elif shell == 'TerminalInteractiveShell':
            return False  # Terminal running IPython
        else:
            return False  # Other type (?)
    except NameError:
        return False      # Probably standard Python interpreter
```

[this works well when I run just the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6f7L.png), but if i want to run the whole file, VScode sense  "%matplotlib widget" as "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Is there a workaround? I need this because in interactive mode there is no option to save the plots to .pgf format, but the same code executed as script, opens a window that has the option to save as .pgf.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/35597119/765091